# ROS2: How to pass arguments from one launch file to a child launch file

Tags: python, ros2

I have a main `bringup.launch.py` launch file of which the launch descriptor includes `child.launch.py` as a *child* launch file like this:

```py
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource

def generate_launch_description():
    package_prefix = get_package_share_directory('child_package')
    argument_for_child = "lala"

    return LaunchDescription([
        # include the child launch file
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([package_prefix, '/launch/child.launch.py'])
        ),
    ])
```

How do I pass an argument from `bringup.launch.py` to `child.launch.py`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `bringup.launch.py` you have to declare the launch argument, and add it to the launch_arguments map like this:

```py
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument

def generate_launch_description():
    package_prefix = get_package_share_directory('child_package')
    argument_for_child = "lala"

    return LaunchDescription([
        # Declare the launc parameter
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'argument_for_child',
            default_value = argument_for_child,
            description = 'Argument for child launch file'),

        # include the child launch file
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([package_prefix, '/launch/child.launch.py'])
            launch_arguments = {'argument_for_child': argument_for_child}.items()
        ),
    ])
```

In `child.launch.py` you read in the passed argument like this:

```py
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration

def generate_launch_description():
    value= LaunchConfiguration('argument_for_child', default='-')

    ...
```

**Note:** this for ROS2 version `Dashing`

Answer (score 2):

Years passed, now there's an official tutorial as well that basically covers what [Floris explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57696570/577001).

[Rolling version (docs.ros.org)](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Tutorials/Intermediate/Launch/Using-Substitutions.html#parent-launch-file)

> ```
> def generate_launch_description():
>     colors = {
>         'background_r': '200'
>     }
>
>     return LaunchDescription([
>         IncludeLaunchDescription(
>             PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([
>                 PathJoinSubstitution([
>                     FindPackageShare('launch_tutorial'),
>                     'example_substitutions_launch.py'
>                 ])
>             ]),
>             launch_arguments={
>                 'turtlesim_ns': 'turtlesim2',
>                 'use_provided_red': 'True',
>                 'new_background_r': TextSubstitution(text=str(colors['background_r']))
>             }.items()
>         )
>     ])
> ```

Nice thing of the official tutorial is it covers `boolean` arg too (which took me awhile to figure out).